# What causes the fopen() function in PHP to turn an "&" in the first parameter (which is a URL) into an "&amp;"

Tags: php

A call to the `fopen()` function in PHP is turning the `&` that are in the first parameter into `&amp;` which is causing the call to `fopen()` to fail due to an invalid URL.  The following snippet is from the apache error log:

```
[Thu Jan 03 15:01:21.306884 2019] [:error] [pid 5285] [client x.x.x.x:46644] PHP Warning:  fopen(http://pi-familyroom:8090?v_ACTION=stat&amp;m_PIN=37): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 0 in /var/www/html/automation/getter.php on line 30
[Thu Jan 03 15:01:21.306918 2019] [:error] [pid 5285] [client x.x.x.x:46644] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/automation/getter.php on line 41
```

Perhaps I've just been looking at this too long at this point and can't see something that is obvious, but I do believe I've tried all kinds of workarounds.  I'm now to the point where I can confirm (as a result of a bit of debug code) that the string IS DEFINITELY intact before the call to `fopen()`.

```
    $q_parms = "?v_ACTION=" . $req_data["v_ACTION"] . '&' . "m_PIN=" . $req_data["m_PIN"];
// Initialize stream
       echo $q_parms;
$req_stream = stream_context_create($req_options);
$req_fileptr = fopen(urldecode($config_vals["baseUrl"] . $q_parms), 'r', false, $req_stream);
```

I hadn't expected the `fopen()` call to interpret the `&` in the way that it is.  My debug echo of the string before the call to `fopen()` shows the following:

```
?v_ACTION=stat&m_PIN=37
```

There is a post here that suggests adding a `User Agent` header to the GET request would solve the problem.  It didn't help in my situation.

Comment: When you echo `$p_parms` does it also show `&` when you "view source" in a browser, or is it `&amp;` ?

Comment: I've never seen `fopen()` do that by itself. That would be the result of using `htmlentities($q_params)`.

Comment: @Evert: the & is seen everywhere except within the parens of the fopen call.

Comment: I’m just going to bite the bullet and change my request to a POST and modify the backend service accordingly.

Comment: @PaulCrovella: you're right.  The call to `fopen()` is now succeeding after resolving a small issue.  In fact, after looking at some network traces of the machine-to-machine conversation I see that the expected response from the upstream server is coming back to the requesting client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved.  Turns out that I had moved the operations to set my headers on the backend server to a path in code that was too late:

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
self.end_headers()
```

Placed these at the beginning of a code path and I'm now getting the expected responses via the PHP stream.